# UICollectionView Cell Frame Has Decimal Origin Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that I created programatically. Each cell in the collection view displays a label, and all the labels have identical properties. Despite this, I noticed that the text contained in each label in the center column of the collection view looked blurry.

A recursive description of the collection view shows that the center cell in the table always has an x origin that is a decimal value:

```
 <UICollectionViewCell: 0xd98c1e0; frame = (242.5 0; 220 45); layer = <CALayer: 0xd98c270>> ...
```

**My questions are: 1) could this be causing the bluriness? and 2) What is the best way to ensure that none of the x and y origins end up having a decimal value? (Aside from manually calculating the layout)**

For reference, here is my UICollectionView code:

```
//subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@implementation LabelLayout

-(BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds{
    return YES;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)prepareLayout
{
    [super prepareLayout];
    _cellCount = [[self collectionView] numberOfItemsInSection:0];
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(220.0f, 45.0f);
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0f;
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20.0f;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would definitely cause blurring as everything is being anti-aliased across two pixels (Note: On a retina screen, you won't see any blurring because each point is actually two pixels so half points technically exist as a single pixel). To fix it you might have to use CGRectIntegral to force the frame to integer bounds. The best way to do that would be:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    for (NSLayoutAttributes *attribute in attributes){
        attribute.frame = CGRectIntegral(attribute.frame);
    }
}
```

You should do the same thing for `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`.